# Random() in Redshift CTE returns wildly incorrect results under certain conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

(Cross posting this from the AWS forums...)

Need a fairly sizable chunk of dummy data for this. I used this list of English words: http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt

I'm seeing a MASSIVE difference in the number of results I get for seemingly equivalent queries involving the random() function within a CTE in Amazon Redshift. (I'm trying to take a random sample - one query returns an actual sample as expected, the other basically just returns the entire list of items I was trying to sample.)

Can somebody take a look at this? Am I doing something wrong? Is there another issue here?

```
/* Create tables to hold words */

create table main_words(word varchar(max));
create table couple_words(word varchar(max));

/* Get some words */

copy main_words
    from 'S3 LOCATION OF CORNCOB FILE'
    credentials 'aws_access_key_id=ID;aws_secret_access_key=KEY' 
    csv;

/* Put a few in another table */

insert into
    couple_words
select top 5000
    word
from
    main_words;

/* Returns about 500 results */

with the_cte as
    (
        select
            word,
            random() as random_value
        from
            main_words
        where
            word not in (select word from couple_words)
    )
select
    count(*)
from
    the_cte
where
    random_value > .99;


/* Returns about 58,000 results (basically, the whole list) */

with the_cte as
    (
        select
            word
        from
            main_words
        where
            word not in (select word from couple_words)
            and random() > .99
    )
select
    count(*)
from
    the_cte;

/* Clean up */

drop table if exists main_words;
drop table if exists couple_words;
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the downvoting? I've shown code, explained my desired result, actual result, and what I've tried... I'm not sure why this isn't a valid question?

Comment: As a workaround: try to replace the CTE by a subquery or a view. (CTEs were introduced in PG-8.4, it could be that Redshit introduced *different behaviour* when re-inplementing it)

Comment: Yes, excellent idea. I've actually already implemented this for my current project, but I was interested in finding an answer either for my own edification or for the purposes of documenting the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try it on a different server?

I just create a sample on **[SqlFidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f961d/2)** with 100 rows plus `random() > 0.9` and result are very similar.

First CTE

```
| count |
|-------|
|     4 |
```

Second CTE

```
| count |
|-------|
|    13 |
```

Average count(*) with 10 runs

```
CTE 1     CTE 2
 8.3       9.8
```

Comment: If this was true, I would expect to get 0 results 99% of the time, but that's not the case... Also, functions are applied to every row, not applied once. To demonstrate, run `select * from main_words where random() > .99` without the CTE.

Comment: You are right. Also I just check in postgre 9.3 and `random()` generate a value for each comparasion on where. So wasnt that the case neither.

Comment: Please chek my update. I run a similar test. Let me know if that match your case.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but... I tagged this with Postgres because Redshift is based on an old version of Postgres, but the code bases are entirely different. So, just because something works on Postgres doesn't mean it will work on Redshift. HOWEVER, this is further evidence to me that it's a Redshift bug, so thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect some funky query rewriting. If you have to have the inner query, you can use LIMIT 2147483647 inside and see what comes up.